# Do we make object of class having private construtor?

Tags: c#, constructor, private-members

Someone ask me that do we make an object of class having private constructor

for E.g

```
    Class Parent
    {
        Private Parent()
        {
        }
    }
```

Since i made a private constructor for class Parent.so it is obvious that we can't make object of Parent class.but is there is a way to make Parent class object without changing the private constructor into public?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think we *understand* the example, but as a tip: when giving an example, it is preferable to post actual code that would compile, unless the question is about a compile problem - so `class` and `private`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an instance of `Parent` *outside* that class, but:

- You can still create classes derived from `Parent` if they're *nested* classes within Parent, and those could have non-private constructed.
- Code (including static methods, most commonly) within the `Parent` type can create instances of `Parent` so you might have a static factory method, but not expose any constructors directly. For example:

  ```
  public class Parent
  {
      private Parent {}

      public static Parent CreateParent()
      {
          return new Parent();
      }
  }
  ```

It can sometimes be useful to have this sort of approach, if you want to apply argument validation (etc) *before* creating an instance of a type, and you therefore want to force everything through named factory methods. That can also make code easier to read, particularly if you want to have different ways of creating an instance from the same number of values. `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`, `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` etc are good examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the private constructor within the `Parent` class. Therefore this is allowed:

```
class Parent
{
    private Parent()
    {
    }

    public static Parent Create()
    {
        return new Parent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection` but that can be considered cheating to get around the original design.

If you own the class, you should make use of the `Factory` by including a static method in the Parent class that returns an instance of your object.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way of implementation of singleton design pattern. You can have a public static field in your class and a getter for it. And when your class is loaded, the instance in it will be created and you will not be able to create a new instance outside your class, but you will be able to get the only instance.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a public static method in that class which creates an object of this class and returns it. This is how Singleton Pattern is normally applied in some languages.